# Rotating a single image texture for multiple instances

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image

I have a node setup for a single image texture (actually its a set of images) tiled floor. For variance I grouped the spec, normal, occ images then rotated them randomly using the Object Info. The end result looks pretty good, but it I dont think the node setup is very efficient. If I want to change the image, I need to go into each group and manually change 4 images for the 4 different rotated tiles. Is there a way to change the rotation of an image AFTER the using the image texture node to make changing an image quicker?

I've checked out a similar post [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/different-image-textures-for-one-material-cycles), but this is different because I want to rotate the same image, not replace it with a rotated image.

[image: Random tiles]
[image: Image Group setup][image: Node Setup][image: Rotation Group]

Comment: What's an 'occ' file? occlusion map? What do you apply it to?

Comment: Occ is one of the export options in crazy bump. I believe it is a greyscale map that it adds to (multiplies) the dark areas in a texture.

Comment: :) what about a specocc file? Can you join a  Specularity map and an occlusion map in one file? If so how do you apply it?

Comment: Spec would be a mask that is used to mix your base shader with a glossy. Basically shows were to add highlights.

Comment: The spec mask is used as the factor in the mix shader/node. Black is base and White becomes glossy when base is in top socket and glossy is in bottom. Sorry. I'm on mobile so you get the terse answer.

Comment: I found this topic about rotation of an image texture tile: https:https://blenderartists.org/t/random-tile-placement-and-rotation-in-cycles-material/641688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's currently not possible. To "rotate" a texture, you actually rotate it's mapping, so it must be done before hand.