# Where do I find the equivalent of Blender Render's texture slot panel in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm watching [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/XEZYcyi7JC0?t=1289), except I'm doing it in *cycles*.

I'm at *21:29*, and I've noticed that he has a panel with texture slots in it..

[image]

I do not have this panel though..

[image]

It could be because i'm using cycles, or because I'm using a far newer version of blender than him.. Can anyone help me figure out how I'm supposed to create the 3 texture slots without the panel?

Comment: could this answer help http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/different-image-textures-for-one-material-cycles?

Comment: Cycles doesn't use texture slots for materials, only nodes.

Answer (score 1):

[image] Switching to the cycles render and then to the blender internal render removes the texture slots. The video also mentions that they are using blender render and not cycles.

Comment: Switching between Cycles and Internal doesn't remove texture slots.. They are just different tools, one has texture slots, another - doesn't and tries to convert that to appropriate textures (it won't be able to do that because see above).